# Is there a way to calculate the open/not responded messages in meta business for Facebook and Instagram business account?

Tags: facebook, metadata

I am facing an issue of tracking the backlog of the business account for facbook and instigram as well as whats app and not able to define how many messages are still open or not answered in the queue?

didn't find an report to get this automaticly without the manual work of counting them